# Escaping RegEx in JSON for Hive

Tags: json, regex, hive, impala

I have a JSON file in which I put my SQL query and it will later on be run automatically on Hive.

Structure of the JSON is as-follow:

```
{
    "name": "query1",
    "query": "select regexp_extract(column, '(.*)\\s\\|', 1) as column_one from data"
}
```

The idea is to extract everything until the first space + vertical bar.

For a given example, when I try in Hive, it works as expected:

```
select regexp_extract('First part | Second Part', '(.*)\\s\\|', 1) as column_one;

First part
```

As you can see you already need one more backslash for `\s` and `\|` otherwise is does not work in Hive.
However when run automatically using the JSON file, I get the following:

```
Fir
```

Then I understood you need another backslash to escape it in JSON so I went with the following:

```
{
    "name": "query1",
    "query": "select regexp_extract(column, '(.*)\\\s\\\|', 1) as column_one from data"
}
```

But still, it gives me the `Fir` instead of `First part`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
{
    "name": "query1",
    "query": "select regexp_extract(column, '([^|]*?)[[:space:]]*[|]', 1) as column_one from data"
}
```

Note that

- `([^|]*?)` - Captures any zero or more chars other than `|` as few as possible
- `[[:space:]]*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `[|]` - a literal `|` char (inside a character class, `[...]`, the `|` char is treated as a literal pipe symbol).